# Calculate z-score in data bunch but excluding N.A

Tags: python, pandas

So I got this bunch of data with N.A. values in them:

[Data Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVlKo.jpg)

So how do I get the z-score of each column while excluding the N.A. values? Such that the z-score output looks like this?

[Z-Score value output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5XiW.jpg)

So for this is what I have, which is based on previous questions:

```
cols = list(df.columns)
df[cols]
for col in cols:
    col_zscore = col + '_zscore'
    df[col_zscore] = (df[col] - df[col].mean())/df[col].std(ddof="N.A.")
```

but I got TypeError.

Please help, I am really a beginner at this.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that 'col' needs to be explicitly declared as an integer or that list needs to be declared as an array of integers (so the compiler can make an assumption about col). Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) first `N.A.` to `NaN` and convert values to `float`:

```
df = df.replace({'N.A.': np.nan}).astype(float)

for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'PE Trail':
        col_zscore = col + '_zscore'
        df[col_zscore] = (df[col] - df[col].mean())/df[col].std()

print (df)
   PE Trail  PE fwd   PB  PE fwd_zscore  PB_zscore
0       NaN    1.00  1.0       1.317465   0.707107
1       NaN    0.50  NaN       0.146385        NaN
2       NaN    0.00  0.5      -1.024695  -0.707107
3       NaN    0.25  NaN      -0.439155        NaN
```

Also `type` of value in parameter `ddof` in [`std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html) is `int`.

---

If use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), parameter `na_values` causes converting `N.A.` to `NaN`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""PE Trail;PE fwd;PB
N.A.;1;1
N.A.;0.5;N.A.
N.A.;0;0.5
N.A.;0.25;N.A."""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", na_values='N.A.')
print (df)
   PE Trail  PE fwd   PB
0       NaN    1.00  1.0
1       NaN    0.50  NaN
2       NaN    0.00  0.5
3       NaN    0.25  NaN
```